# Using Gaussian Mixture model to create binary image of lungs

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to segment lungs on a CT scan using Sklearn's Gaussian Mixture. The code is running fine but I
am getting a very jumbled up output.

Here is the code:

```
def GaussianMixtureSegmentaion(image, fill_lung_structures = True):

    
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        
        twod = image[i,:,:]
        np.random.seed(1)
        gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='diag', max_iter=100, n_init = 1)

        gmm.fit(twod)

        label_data = gmm.predict(twod)
        #label_data = label_data.reshape(twod.shape)

        mask[i,:,:] = label_data


    labels = measure.label(mask)
    
    # Pick the pixel in the very corner to determine which label is air.
    #   Improvement: Pick multiple background labels from around the patient
    #   More resistant to "trays" on which the patient lays cutting the air 
    #   around the person in half
    background_label = labels[0,0,0]
    
    #Fill the air around the person
    mask[background_label == labels] = 2

    
    # Method of filling the lung structures (that is superior to something like 
    # morphological closing)
    if fill_lung_structures:
        # For every slice we determine the largest solid structure
        for i, axial_slice in enumerate(mask):
            axial_slice = axial_slice - 1
            labeling = measure.label(axial_slice)
            l_max = largest_label_volume(labeling, bg=0)
            
            if l_max is not None: #This slice contains some lung
                mask[i][labeling != l_max] = 1

    
    mask -= 1 #Make the image actual binary
    mask = 1-mask # Invert it, lungs are now 1
    
    # Remove other air pockets insided body
    labels = measure.label(mask, background=0)
    l_max = largest_label_volume(labels, bg=0)
    if l_max is not None: # There are air pockets
        mask[labels != l_max] = 0

    
    return mask
```

The input is a 3d ct scan of the lungs. I iterate through each slice and use the GaussianMixture on each slice to try to cluster the slice into two parts (essentialy the light and dark areas). Am I using this in the wrong way?

Attached is a picture of an example of one of the slices of the lung:

[image: Image of one of the lung slices]

I believe this should be easy to do - I just want to make it a binary picture.

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your cod snippets (done it for you here).